# How to iterate over a dataframe with list passed as function argument?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, list, typeerror

| TV | newspaper | radio | Sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 87 | 13 | 23 | 123 |
| 89 | 09 | 34 | 169 |

Hi,all! first post, so I apologize for the formatting.

I created this function and it works when I set a feature equal to a single column name, but I want to be able to pass in a list for multiple features (tv and radio) for example.

```
def coefficient_intercept(df,features,target):


  ybar = np.mean(df[target])
  xbar = np.mean(df[features])

  yi = df[target]
  xi = df[features]

  coefficient =  sum((yi - ybar) * (xi - xbar))  /  sum((xi - xbar)**2)
  intercept = ybar - coefficient * xbar

  index = [features]
  data = np.array([[coefficient],[intercept]])
  
  return pd.DataFrame(data = data.T, index=index,columns =['coefficient','intercept'])
```

[code/output in colab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vmDEd.png)

I've tried a few different loops and a couple iloc methods that didn't get me far.
Mainly, I keep running into this error when I pass in ['TV','newspaper'] for example, and I want to understand where the string or'str'  part is coming from? Thanks for your time!

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py:3430: FutureWarning: In a future version, DataFrame.mean(axis=None) will return a scalar mean over the entire DataFrame. To retain the old behavior, use 'frame.mean(axis=0)' or just 'frame.mean()'
return mean(axis=axis, dtype=dtype, out=out, **kwargs)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 <ipython-input-31-25f7ee028e22> in <cell line: 1>()
1 coefficient_intercept(df,features = ['TV','newspaper'],target = 'sales')

 <ipython-input-28-5878e49e78b4> in coefficient_intercept(df, features, target)
15       xi = df[features]
16 
17       coefficient =  sum((yi - ybar) * (xi - xbar))  /  sum((xi - xbar)**2)
18       intercept = ybar - coefficient * xbar
19 

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str
```

```
def coefficient_intercept(df,features,target):


  for column in df.columns:
    if column in features:

      ybar = np.mean(df[target])
      xbar = np.mean(df[features])

      yi = df[target]
      xi = df[features]

      coefficient =  sum((yi - ybar) * (xi - xbar))  /  sum((xi - xbar)**2)
      intercept = ybar - coefficient * xbar

      index = [features]
      data = np.array([[coefficient],[intercept]])
      
      
      print(pd.DataFrame(data = data.T, index=index,columns =['coefficient','intercept']))
```

Comment: Your problem is in the (yi-ybar)*(xi-xbar) part. Try printing that out in both cases and you'll see NaNs in the second case. You'll need to fix those NaNs before you sum() or anything else.
What are you trying to do? For correlation coefficients related stuff, there are already built-in functions in python, pandas, numpy such as .corr()

Comment: @hikerjobs Yeah, for sure! I was just trying to do simple linear regression 'by hand' to better understand the math. Probably not the greatest way to learn it lol, but yeah I was more curious from a general coding standpoint about why it works until I add the []'s around the 'feature' argument and try to pass in a list. I'm assuming the dtype changes, but how would one get around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to generalize to more features, you have to use 2D-arrays even if you have only one feature:

```
def coefficient_intercept(df, features, target):

  # Convert as 2D-array if it's not already the case
  features = features if isinstance(features, list) else [features]
  target = [target]

  # Get values as numpy array
  yi = df[target].values
  xi = df[features].values

  # Compute the mean
  ybar = np.mean(yi, axis=0)
  xbar = np.mean(xi, axis=0)

  # Linear Regression
  coefficient =  sum((yi - ybar) * (xi - xbar))  /  sum((xi - xbar)**2)
  intercept = ybar - coefficient * xbar

  # Build your dataframe
  return pd.DataFrame({'coefficient': coefficient,
                       'intercept': intercept},
                      index=features)
```

Output:

```
>>> coefficient_intercept(df, 'radio', 'Sales')
       coefficient  intercept
radio     4.181818  26.818182

>>> coefficient_intercept(df, ['radio', 'TV'], 'Sales')
       coefficient    intercept
radio     4.181818    26.818182
TV       23.000000 -1878.000000
```